# Как вернуть код в начало и запустить?

Tags: java

Есть код через который можно выполнить вход прописав необходимый логин и пароль, если ты ввел логин неправильно то программа пишет "Error".

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я вписывал неправильный логин, программа автоматически перезагружалась/начала сначала?

Вот код программы входа:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your login: ");

        String login = str.nextLine();

        if(login.equals("Admin")) {

            System.out.print("Enter your password: ");

            String password = str.nextLine();

            if(password.equals("123")) {
                System.out.print("Welcome...");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте цикл, например `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loginValid = false;
    while (!loginValid) {
        System.out.print("Enter your login: ");

        String login = str.nextLine();

        if (login.equals("Admin")) {

            System.out.print("Enter your password: ");

            String password = str.nextLine();

            if (password.equals("123")) {
                System.out.print("Welcome...");
                loginValid = true;
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```java
boolean success;
do {
    try {
        //ваш код
        success = true;
    } catch (Error e) {
        success = false;
    }
} while(!success);
```